# How can I restore Windows 7 to the pc

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I had windows 7 and installed ubuntu, but I don't like it, so I'd like to remove it and back to windows 7. can you tell the steps?

Comment: Thanks for using ubuntu! but what makes you dislike it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have used live disk to install it --

1. Put your windows 7 disk in the drive. Reboot and choose to boot from dvd.
2. Use "Repair" option and then choose "Repair Start Up "
3. Once successfully completed, see if windows 7 is booting correctly as before. If not then follow - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392. (use /fixboot and /fixmbr option)
4. If so, in windows 7 RUN prompt, type "diskmgmt.msc" and press enter.
5. Delete partitions that belong to ubuntu for freeing up space.

If you have using WUBI , just go to add/remove programs and remove it.